# Где нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Вот уж не знаю почему.  Куда поставить запятую?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Здесь запятая не нужна. "Почему" здесь член предложения, в таких случаях обособление не требуется.

Хотя иногда запятую перед "почему" все-таки проставляют как авторский знак, подчеркивая смысловое ударение на это "почему". В таком случае "почему" рассматривается как короткое самостоятельное предложение с опущенными словами типа "почему [это происходит]". Но, повторюсь, это чисто авторский стилистический прием, далеко не всеми принимаемый. В обычном, не экспрессивном тексте лучше не использовать